# How to Get an Android openRawResource as a Variable?

Tags: android, string, variables, resources, arguments

I have an int/string(s) that is passed from one fragment to another. For each way I code it, I get a NPE at line 67 (see where 67 is below). I dont know If I am going about it in the correct way so please look thru my methods and include some code in your answer.

Thnx.

What passes the arguments:

```
. . .
        int rawRes = R.raw.regulatory_list;//<--THIS IS THE RES I NEED TO PASS
        args.putInt("KEY_RAW_RES", rawRes);

        boolean isRawRes = true;
    args.putBoolean("KEY_IS_RAW_RES", isRawRes);

        ListViewFragment lvf = new ListViewFragment();
        lcFT.replace(R.id.discriptionListContainer, lvf).commit();
        lvf.setArguments(args);
. . .
```

ListViewFragment's onActivityCreated:

```
. . .
private static final String KEY_URL = "KEY_URL";
    private static final String KEY_IS_RAW_RES = "KEY_IS_RAW_RES";
    private static final String KEY_RAW_RES = "KEY_RAW_RES";
. . .

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

// Get the string to query from last Fragment and pass it to this
        // Fragment
        Bundle args = this.getArguments();

        String url = args.getString(KEY_URL);
        boolean rawRes = args.getBoolean(KEY_IS_RAW_RES);

        int fileName = (Integer) null;//<--THIS IS LINE 67!!
        fileName = args.getInt(KEY_RAW_RES);

        this.runJsonFile(url, jsonSrc, fileName);
}

private void runJsonFile(String url, boolean rawRes, int fileName) {

    if (rawRes == true) {
        getFromRawRes(fileName);
    } else {
        getFromURL(url);
    }
}

    private void getFromRawRes(int fileName) {
//      InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.regulatory_list);
        InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(fileName);
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromFile(file);
        callback(json);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I change lines 67 - 68 as per Raghav Sood answer to:

```
//      int fileName = (Integer) null;
        int fileName = args.getInt(KEY_RAW_RES);
```

This got the class past the NPE - Thnx!!

Comment: Why are you trying to cast `null` to an `Integer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting a null value to an integer variable. There is no conceivable scenario in which this will not result in a NullPointerException, since you are using null in the first place. In Java, and several other languages, primitive data types like integer, double, char etc cannot be null.

Answer (score 2):

Also to add, as well as your casting of `null` to `Integer`, this method makes absolutely no logical sense whatsoever:

```
private void runJsonFile(String url, String resType, int fileName) {
        String rawRes = null;
        if (ListViewFragment.KEY_RES_TYPE == rawRes) {
            getFromRawRes(fileName);
        } else {
            getFromURL(url);
        }
    }
}
```

This will *always* go to the else block. You're initializing `rawRes` to `null`, then testing it against a `final String` that is non-null. There is never an instance that this `if` statement evaluates to true.

Comment: Thnx: I had just edited that befor you posted this answer but thnx for catching it. `String rawRes = KEY_RES_TYPE;`

Comment: Give me a min to finish building it out! Missed coping it all over.

Comment: Again Thinx, Give me a min to finish building it out! Just needed to get it running - Now I have to change it to a boolean. Patients

Comment: Just sayin'. There's no reason to build it out here, anyway, since your question's answered.